# How can I create a map-style index in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a map-style index, like `map` in Golang or also called ascociative array in Javascript. I need the key of the map to be `account_id` and the `value` of the map to be an ordered list of records. Is it possible? I found that Postgres has `expression` indexes, but I don't know how can you assemble a map from expressions with an `OR` condition.

My real world example:

I have a table containing account value transfers, and I am currently using this query to get latest balance of the account:

```
SELECT
        valtr_id,
        from_id,
        to_id,
        from_balance,
        to_balance
FROM value_transfer v
WHERE
        (v.block_num<=2435013) AND
        (
                (v.to_id = 22479) OR
                (v.from_id = 22479) 
        )
ORDER BY v.block_num DESC,v.valtr_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

The `OR` has to be used because an account may have an outgoing transfer (`from_id` is set) or an incoming transfer (`to_id` is set). If I would have an associative array index, that would hold `account_id` (which would be derived as a condition: `if from_id==account_id OR to_id=account_id`) then Postgres could lookup this index using `account_id` to get the list of records , which would be already sorted. Since the index would already considering an OR condition, I wouldn't need to build a list of records with `from_id=22479`, then `to_id=22479` and them compare them to find which record has the latest timestamp to get latest balance of the account, like I am doing it now with my current query. (The `block_num` is the blockchain block where the transfer took place)

Currently this query takes lots of time with a huge database of 100 million records, here is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of it:

```
postgres-> \g
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1592973.24..1592973.24 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=86448.709..86448.710 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1592973.24..1595439.02 rows=986312 width=31) (actual time=86448.707..86448.707 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: block_num DESC, valtr_id DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on value_transfer v  (cost=35340.86..1588041.68 rows=986312 width=31) (actual time=851.598..85082.223 rows=1387411 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((to_id = 22479) OR (from_id = 22479))
               Filter: (block_num <= 2435013)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 298923
               Heap Blocks: exact=274549
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=35340.86..35340.86 rows=1291543 width=0) (actual time=729.917..729.917 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vt_to_id_idx  (cost=0.00..27233.03 rows=1004862 width=0) (actual time=575.558..575.558 rows=1364039 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (to_id = 22479)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vt_from_id_idx  (cost=0.00..7614.68 rows=286681 width=0) (actual time=154.356..154.356 rows=352366 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (from_id = 22479)
 Planning time: 0.367 ms
 Execution time: 86448.817 ms
(16 rows)

postgres=>
```

The table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE value_transfer (
    valtr_id            BIGSERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    tx_id               BIGINT          REFERENCES transaction(tx_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    block_id            INT             REFERENCES block(block_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    block_num           INT             NOT NULL,
    from_id             INT             NOT NULL,
    to_id               INT             NOT NULL,
    value               NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    from_balance        NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    to_balance          NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    kind                CHAR            NOT NULL,
    depth               INT             DEFAULT 0,
    error               TEXT            NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX vt_tx_idx          ON  value_transfer  USING   btree   ("tx_id");
CREATE INDEX vt_block_num_idx   ON  value_transfer      USING   btree   ("block_num");
CREATE INDEX vt_block_id_idx    ON  value_transfer      USING   btree   ("block_id");
CREATE INDEX vt_from_id_idx     ON  value_transfer  USING   btree   ("from_id");
CREATE INDEX vt_to_id_idx       ON  value_transfer  USING   btree   ("to_id");
```

`from_id` and `to_id` are foreign keys to account table:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    account_id          SERIAL          PRIMARY KEY,
    owner_id            INT             NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    last_balance        NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    num_tx              BIGINT          DEFAULT 0,
    ts_created          INT             DEFAULT 0,
    block_created       INT             DEFAULT 0,
    deleted             SMALLINT        DEFAULT 0,
    block_sd            INT             DEFAULT 0,
    address             TEXT            NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

**EDIT:**

Execution plan comparison of the UNION query proposed by Lukasz versus the old query

UNION query:

```
 Limit  (cost=1668089.09..1668089.10 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6115.484..6115.485 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1668089.09..1671668.88 rows=1431916 width=32) (actual time=6115.483..6115.483 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: v.block_num DESC, v.valtr_id DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Append  (cost=21229.61..1660929.51 rows=1431916 width=32) (actual time=255.166..5446.818 rows=1413507 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on value_transfer v  (cost=21229.61..1229731.99 rows=1134056 width=32) (actual time=255.165..4312.769 rows=1102867 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (to_id = 22479)
                     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 9412580
                     Filter: (block_num <= 2435013)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=32392 lossy=132879
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vt_to_id_idx  (cost=0.00..20946.10 rows=1134071 width=0) (actual time=241.632..241.632 rows=1102867 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (to_id = 22479)
               ->  Index Scan using vt_from_id_idx on value_transfer v_1  (cost=0.57..416878.36 rows=297860 width=32) (actual time=0.056..952.883 rows=310640 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (from_id = 22479)
                     Filter: (block_num <= 2435013)
 Planning time: 0.319 ms
 Execution time: 6115.539 ms
(17 rows)
```

THE OR CONDITION query (my original query):

```
 Limit  (cost=1276124.75..1276124.75 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=7860.439..7860.440 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1276124.75..1279694.24 rows=1427797 width=32) (actual time=7860.437..7860.437 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: block_num DESC, valtr_id DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on value_transfer v  (cost=27162.56..1268985.76 rows=1427797 width=32) (actual time=304.197..7194.825 rows=1387411 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((to_id = 22479) OR (from_id = 22479))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 13260750
               Filter: (block_num <= 2435013)
               Heap Blocks: exact=37782 lossy=186738
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=27162.56..27162.56 rows=1431937 width=0) (actual time=288.359..288.359 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vt_to_id_idx  (cost=0.00..20946.11 rows=1134072 width=0) (actual time=216.708..216.708 rows=1102867 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (to_id = 22479)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vt_from_id_idx  (cost=0.00..5502.55 rows=297865 width=0) (actual time=71.649..71.649 rows=310640 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (from_id = 22479)
 Planning time: 0.257 ms
 Execution time: 7860.481 ms
(16 rows)
```

Using the UNION query the execution is faster by 1.7 seconds.

**EDIT 2**

This simple query is amazinlgy fast.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
        valtr_id,
        from_id,
        to_id,
        from_balance,
        to_balance,
        block_num
FROM value_transfer v
WHERE v.block_num<=2435013 AND v.from_id = 22479
LIMIT 1

 Limit  (cost=0.57..1.97 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.047..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using vt_from_id_idx on value_transfer v  (cost=0.57..416878.36 rows=297860 width=32) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (from_id = 22479)
         Filter: (block_num <= 2435013)
 Planning time: 0.392 ms
 Execution time: 0.089 ms
(6 rows)
```

But if it is `OR`-ed , it takes a lot more. There must be some problem in telling Postgres to make a UNION between two queries. Maybe writing a PL/PGSQL would be better

Comment: Composite indexes on (block_num, to_id) and  (block_num, from_id) would probably help (Maybe in swapped order, but I dont understand your data model)

Comment: @wildplasser I have added the composite keys as Lukasz suggested, but I am not seeing the EXPLAIN ANALYZE using them. Will try to add in reverse order now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try rewriting it as:

```
--or-expansion
SELECT
        valtr_id,
        from_id,
        to_id,
        from_balance,
        to_balance,
        block_num
FROM value_transfer v
WHERE v.block_num<=2435013 AND v.to_id = 22479
UNION ALL
SELECT
        valtr_id,
        from_id,
        to_id,
        from_balance,
        to_balance,
        block_num
FROM value_transfer v
WHERE v.block_num<=2435013 AND v.from_id = 22479              
ORDER BY block_num DESC,valtr_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

And add two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON value_transfer(from_id, block_num DESC);
CREATE INDEX idx_2 ON value_transfer(to_id, block_num DESC);
```

Comment: thanks! but I have an error with this query: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "v"
LINE 18: ORDER BY v.block_num DESC,v.valtr_id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: @Nulik Please check now

Comment: Thanks again! The modifications you proposed increased the speed by 1.7 seconds. But I still think an associative map index would be faster. Do you know if it is possible to do in Postgres? If not, maybe I should create a table and store the `ID`s of value_transfer record in a `bytea` variable?

Comment: Kind of, create my own index in a Postgres table.

Comment: could the problem be that the index `idx_1` and `idx_2` isn't being used? It doesn't appear in  EXPLAIN ANALYZE I have posted in EDIT section

Answer (score 0):

Try please this, it must be much better.

```
(
SELECT valtr_id,
       from_id,
       to_id,
       from_balance,
       to_balance,
       block_num
  FROM value_transfer v
 WHERE v.block_num<=2435013 AND
       v.to_id = 22479
 ORDER BY block_num DESC,valtr_id DESC
 LIMIT 1
)
 UNION ALL
(
SELECT valtr_id,
       from_id,
       to_id,
       from_balance,
       to_balance,
       block_num
  FROM value_transfer v
 WHERE v.block_num<=2435013 AND 
       v.from_id = 22479              
 ORDER BY block_num DESC,valtr_id DESC
 LIMIT 1
 )
 ORDER BY block_num DESC,valtr_id DESC
 LIMIT 1
```